# Past events in EKCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventstore

I'm trying to get all the events from a determined `EKCalendar`, but if I call `eventsMatching Predicate:` with a predicate generated with `predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:` and a past '`startDate`' I get a null object. It's a bug? Or there is no way I can retrive the past events?

EDIT (NSData decalarations):

```
[[self eventStore] predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:syncedCalendars]
```

Comment: Can you post your nsdate declaration and nspredictate?

Comment: Edited as you requested

Comment: Maybe the timespan is too long. `distantPast` returns the 30th of December in Year 1 for me, and `distantFuture` returns 1st of January in the year 4001. Have your tried using a smaller timespan, like the last 3 months or so?

Comment: Using [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0] also return null. The 'pastest' date I can use is 1/1/2010. I would know why

Comment: EDIT: Nope, even with 1/1/2010 return NULL. I will file a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code to to:

```
    NSDate* futureDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
    [[self eventStore] predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate date] endDate: futureDate calendars:syncedCalendars]
```

Also make sure that your syncedCalendars is NSArray type.

Comment: It's not this problem, I want retrive the PAST events. Passing [NSDate date] will not retrive past events.

Comment: I think there is some issue with [NSDate distantPast] call. I couldn't make it worked either. Maybe try subtract time interval from [NSDate date] to get date in the past.

Comment: Yep, what I've done :) But I can't further that 1/1/2010, even with 29/12/2009 I get a null array.